# Sending a daily summary email with hang-fire and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I need to send a daily summary email to all users but I am unsure where exactly I should trigger it.

I have made a class for sending the emails :

```
public class SummaryEmailBusiness
{
    private MyDbContext _db;
    private IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public SummaryEmailBusiness(MyDbContext db, IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _db = db;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    public void SendAllSummaries()
    {
        foreach(var user in _db.AspNetUsers)
        {
            //send user a summary
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `ConfigureServices()` I have registered service and hangfire:

```
services.AddHangfire(config =>
    config.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddTransient<SummaryEmailBusiness>();
```

And in `Configure()`  added

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

Now I am stuck.  Hang-fire docs say I need to do something like :

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() =>  SendAllSummaries() , Cron.Daily);
```

I am not sure how to do this so that the class gets initiated with dependent services injected.  How do I reference the `SendAllSummaries()` method of instantiated service?

What is best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is just register job (somewhere after calling `UseHangfireServer`) like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<SummaryEmailBusiness>(x => x.SendAllSummaries(), Cron.Daily);
```

Doing `services.AddHangfire` already registers special `JobActivator` which not only resolves job instances from asp.net core DI container, but also creates new scope for each job, which is important in your case, because most likely your `MyDbContext` is registered as scoped.

Comment: Do I call that inside ConfigureServices()?  I tried and got `JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API`.  I tried setting `JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");` but it gave error for connection string (same connection string im using to register my db context and works fine for that)

Comment: @Guerrilla you need to call it at some point after `app.UseHangfireServer()`. So, at least in `Configure`, not in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Ahh very cool.  I can see the task in dashboard now.  Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hangfire is using CRON expressions. Cron.Daily is shorthand for the CRON expression "0 0 * * *" which is run at midnight daily.   If you want to run it at another time of day e.g. 6 am you could do...

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<SummaryEmailBusiness>(x => x.SendAllSummaries(), "0 6 * * *");
```

Read more about [CRON Expressions here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression)

Comment: Ahh that's much better.  Thanks for taking time to point that out.